# Can you replace DatePickerTextBox with a different TextBox in DatePicker and still get the validation functionality?

Tags: wpf, validation, datepicker, controltemplate

I replaced the `DatePickerTextBox` in the control template of `DatePicker`, and it no longer ensures a valid date value for the text entered. I tested different strings with a plain `DatePickerTextBox`, too, and it didn't validate them, so it must be some kind of interaction between `DatePickerTextBox` and `DatePicker`. Is there a way to get that interaction with a different `TextBox` control in the control template that isn't `DatePickerTextBox`, or will I have to recreate that validation in my own custom control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short explanation with answer:**

In the `OnApplyTemplate` method of a custom `TextBox` control, I added:

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    LostFocus += OnLostFocus;

    base.OnApplyTemplate();
}
```

And then the method:

```
private void OnLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!Text.Equals(oldText))
    {
        DateTime d;
        if (!DateTime.TryParse(Text, out d))
        {
            Text = oldText;
        }
    }
    oldText = Text;
}
```

**Long explanation of why it doesn't work in the control template if you replace** `DatePickerTextBox`**:**

I poked around in the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/DatePicker.cs) and discovered the following:

In the `OnApplyTemplate` method for `DatePicker`, some handlers are added, specifically for a `DatePickerTextBox`, which it will not apply if it doesn't find one (which explains why `DatePickerTextBox` doesn't validate on its own, either - `DatePicker` adds the handlers, not `DatePickerTextBox`):

```
_textBox = GetTemplateChild(ElementTextBox) as DatePickerTextBox;

if (this.SelectedDate == null)
{
    SetWaterMarkText();
}

if (_textBox != null)
{
    _textBox.AddHandler(TextBox.KeyDownEvent, new KeyEventHandler(TextBox_KeyDown), true);
    _textBox.AddHandler(TextBox.TextChangedEvent, new TextChangedEventHandler(TextBox_TextChanged), true);
    _textBox.AddHandler(TextBox.LostFocusEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(TextBox_LostFocus), true);

    if (this.SelectedDate == null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this._defaultText))
        {
            _textBox.Text = this._defaultText;
            SetSelectedDate();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        _textBox.Text = this.DateTimeToString((DateTime)this.SelectedDate);
    }
}
```

So, tracking it down(here comes the fun part)...

```
private void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SetSelectedDate();
}
```

Then:

```
private void SetSelectedDate()
{
    if (this._textBox != null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this._textBox.Text))
        {
            string s = this._textBox.Text;

            if (this.SelectedDate != null)
            {
                // If the string value of the SelectedDate and the TextBox string value are equal,
                // we do not parse the string again
                // if we do an extra parse, we lose data in M/d/yy format
                // ex: SelectedDate = DateTime(1008,12,19) but when "12/19/08" is parsed it is interpreted as DateTime(2008,12,19)
                string selectedDate = DateTimeToString(this.SelectedDate.Value);

                if (string.Compare(selectedDate, s, StringComparison.Ordinal) == 0)
                {
                    return;
                }
            }

            DateTime? d = SetTextBoxValue(s);
            if (!this.SelectedDate.Equals(d))
            {
                this.SetCurrentValueInternal(SelectedDateProperty, d);
                this.SetCurrentValueInternal(DisplayDateProperty, d);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (this.SelectedDate.HasValue)
            {
                this.SetCurrentValueInternal(SelectedDateProperty, (DateTime?)null);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        DateTime? d = SetTextBoxValue(_defaultText);
        if (!this.SelectedDate.Equals(d))
        {
            this.SetCurrentValueInternal(SelectedDateProperty, d);
        }
    }
}
```

The important thing there is the call to `SetTextBoxValue`:

```
private DateTime? SetTextBoxValue(string s)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
    {
        SafeSetText(s);
        return this.SelectedDate;
    }
    else
    {
        DateTime? d = ParseText(s);

        if (d != null)
        {
            SafeSetText(this.DateTimeToString((DateTime)d));
            return d;
        }
        else
        {
            // If parse error:
            // TextBox should have the latest valid selecteddate value:
            if (this.SelectedDate != null)
            {
                string newtext = this.DateTimeToString((DateTime)this.SelectedDate);
                SafeSetText(newtext);
                return this.SelectedDate;
            }
            else
            {
                SetWaterMarkText();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the important thing there is the call to `ParseText`:

```
private DateTime? ParseText(string text)
{
    DateTime newSelectedDate;

    // TryParse is not used in order to be able to pass the exception to the TextParseError event
    try
    {
        newSelectedDate = DateTime.Parse(text, DateTimeHelper.GetDateFormat(DateTimeHelper.GetCulture(this)));

        if (Calendar.IsValidDateSelection(this._calendar, newSelectedDate))
        {
            return newSelectedDate;
        }
        else
        {
            DatePickerDateValidationErrorEventArgs dateValidationError = new DatePickerDateValidationErrorEventArgs(new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("text", SR.Get(SRID.Calendar_OnSelectedDateChanged_InvalidValue)), text);
            OnDateValidationError(dateValidationError);

            if (dateValidationError.ThrowException)
            {
                throw dateValidationError.Exception;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (FormatException ex)
    {
        DatePickerDateValidationErrorEventArgs textParseError = new DatePickerDateValidationErrorEventArgs(ex, text);
        OnDateValidationError(textParseError);

        if (textParseError.ThrowException && textParseError.Exception != null)
        {
            throw textParseError.Exception;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

The last two methods have the validation I was looking for.  If `ParseText` returns `null`, then `SetTextBoxValue` reverts the value in the text box back to its previous value. Because `DatePicker` is the control that adds the handler, you won't get the validation outside of `DatePicker`. Since `DatePicker` looks specifically for a `DatePickerTextBox` named `"PART_TextBox"` (that is what the `ElementTextBox` string is), a `DatePickerTextBox` must be used, or the handler will not be applied (since `_textbox` will be `null`).